# opencv selectroi function works but selectrois function does not

Tags: python, opencv

My code below works for one roi:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

 #image_path
img_path= 'Query.png'

#read image
img_raw = cv2.imread(img_path)

#select ROI function
roi = cv2.selectROI(img_raw)

#print rectangle points of selected roi
print(roi)

#Crop selected roi from raw image
roi_cropped = img_raw[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0]+roi[2])]

#show cropped image
cv2.imshow("ROI", roi_cropped)

cv2.imwrite("crop.jpeg",roi_cropped)

#hold window
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am able to see both cropped image and the top left and bottom right coordinates of the roi rectangle.

However the below code which is attempting to get multiple rois from the same image doesn't work for me.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

 #image_path
img_path= 'Query.png'

#read image
img_raw = cv2.imread(img_path)

#select ROIs function
ROIs = cv2.selectROIs("Select Rois",img_raw)

#print rectangle points of selected roi
print(ROIs)

#Crop selected rois from raw image

#counter to save image with different name
crop_number=0 

#loop over every bounding box save in array "ROIs"
for rect in ROIs:
    x1=rect[0]
    y1=rect[1]
    x2=rect[2]
    y2=rect[3]

        #crop roi from original image
    img_crop=img_raw[y1:y1+y2,x1:x1+x2]

        #show cropped image
    cv2.imshow("crop"+str(crop_number),img_crop)

    #save cropped image
    cv2.imwrite("crop"+str(crop_number)+".jpeg",img_crop)
        
    crop_number+=1

#hold window
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I draw the rectangle and press enter. I don't see the cropped image. The selected rectangle roi disappears.I also don't have a saved jpeg file in my folder like crop0.jpeg.

I picked up the select ROIs question from:
https://blog.electroica.com/select-roi-or-multiple-rois-bounding-box-in-opencv-python/.
Someone there also asked this question but the writer of the tutorial didn't help the questioner. I am hoping someone here will be able to help me. I am using python 3.10 and opencv-python 4.5.5.64.

Comment: please explain "doesn't work". what does the function return?

Comment: Please read the 4 sentences following "doesn't work". This code line cv2.imwrite("crop"+str(crop_number)+".jpeg",img_crop) should create a cropped jpeg file after I draw the rectangle and press enter but it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: so you're saying `imwrite` did **not** throw an error yet you can't find the file it just wrote? `print(os.getcwd())` -- you describe multiple issues: "don't see the cropped image", "selected rectangle roi disappears", "don't have a saved jpeg". please focus on one. debug your code (step through it, look at variables' values) to figure out when does what happen that deviates from your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christoph. Your comments led me to find the right answer. Looking at the documentation of selectROIs

" ◆ selectROIs()
void cv::selectROIs (   const String &  windowName,
InputArray  img,
std::vector< Rect > &   boundingBoxes,
bool    showCrosshair = true,
bool    fromCenter = false
)

Python:

```
cv.selectROIs(  windowName, img[, showCrosshair[, fromCenter]]  ) ->    boundingBoxes
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

Allows users to select multiple ROIs on the given image.

The function creates a window and allows users to select multiple ROIs using the mouse. Controls: use space or enter to finish current selection and start a new one, use esc to terminate multiple ROI selection process.

Parameters
windowName  name of the window where selection process will be shown.
img image to select a ROI.
boundingBoxes   selected ROIs.
showCrosshair   if true crosshair of selection rectangle will be shown.
fromCenter  if true center of selection will match initial mouse position. In opposite case a corner of selection rectangle will correspont to the initial mouse position.
Note
The function sets it's own mouse callback for specified window using cv::setMouseCallback(windowName, ...). After finish of work an empty callback will be set for the used window."

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga0f11fad74a6432b8055fb21621a0f893

helped me figure out how to use keyboard buttons to go from one roi to another roi.